# Идентификатор формы при serialize()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ооп, mvc

Если выполнить на стороне js (при sumbit формы, например) `$(this).serialize()`, то в переменной получим данные формы в виде строки, которую можно спокойно передавать при помощи ajax на сервер. Всё отлично. А как на стороне сервера различать данные какой формы прилетели? Например, есть контроллер и экшн `actionTest` страницы. На него прилетают ajax с данными форм. Допустим, на странице есть две формы, и данные двух этих форм отправляются на `actionTest`. Как внутри определить, от какой формы пришли данные? Как идентифицировать форму? - нужно ведь решить, что с этими данными делать и т.п.

Comment: Можно добавить скрытый input с идентификатором формы который потом проверять на стороне сервера.

Comment: Тогда имеет смысл их объединить. Разные по сути формы должны отправляться на разные обработчики, а пускать через один - извращенство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я люблю оборачивать имена полей в формах, например

```
<input type="text" name="Item[id]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="Item[caption]" value="Лопатка" />
```

Тогда на стороне сервера можно сразу понять что что-то пришло и передать методу все сразу

```
$item = isset($_POST['Item']) ? $_POST['Item'] : null;
if ($item) $handler->handleItem($item);
$group = isset($_POST['Group']) ? $_POST['Group'] : null;
if ($group) $handler->handleGroup($group);
```